# Telegram bot on mac

Tags: python, macos, aiogram

We wrote a bot on Windows, everything works fine, put it on the mac, gives an error connecting to the host, we do not understand what is the matter. I attach the text of the program below. Screenshots with errors too.

```
import re
import os
import sqlite3
from random import choice
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
from aiogram.utils.keyboard import ReplyKeyboardBuilder, KeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardBuilder, InlineKeyboardButton
from aiogram.types import FSInputFile

token = "тут наш токен"

bot = Bot(token=token, parse_mode='HTML')
dp = Dispatcher()

db = sqlite3.connect('data.db')
sql = db.cursor()

sql.execute("""
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
    id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
    username TEXT NOT NULL,
    create_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)
""")

sql.execute("""
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS themes (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    title TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    course INTEGER DEFAULT 1
)
""")

sql.execute("""
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS logs (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    user_id BIGINT,
    variant_number INTEGER,
    theme_id INTEGER,
    create_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (theme_id) REFERENCES themes(id)
)
""")
db.commit()


@dp.message(commands=['start'])
async def on_start(message: types.Message):
    user = message.from_user

    sql.execute("INSERT INTO users (id, username) VALUES (?,?) ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE SET username=?",
                (user.id, user.username, user.username))
    db.commit()

    markup = ReplyKeyboardBuilder()

    for i in range(1, 5):
        markup.add(KeyboardButton(text=f'{i} Курс'))

    markup.adjust(2)

    await bot.send_message(chat_id=user.id,
                           text='Добро пожаловать...\n<code>Designed by i923b</code>',
                           reply_markup=markup.as_markup(resize_keyboard=True))


@dp.message(lambda m: re.match('[1-4] Курс', m.text))
async def get_themes(message: types.Message):

    course = re.search('\d', message.text)[0]
    sql.execute("SELECT id, title FROM themes WHERE course = ?",(course,))
    rows = sql.fetchall()

    markup = InlineKeyboardBuilder()

    for id, title in rows:
        markup.row(InlineKeyboardButton(text=title, callback_data=f"get_task-{id}"))

    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, text='Выберите тему:', reply_markup=markup.as_markup())


@dp.callback_query(lambda call: call.data.startswith('get_task'))
async def task_handler(call: types.callback_query):

    theme_id = call.data.split('-')[-1]
    user_id = call.from_user.id

    sql.execute("SELECT title FROM themes WHERE id = ?", (theme_id,))

    theme = sql.fetchone()[0]
    files = os.listdir(theme)

    variant = choice(files)
    variant_number = variant.split('.')[0]
    await bot.send_photo(user_id, caption=f'Ваш вариант: {variant_number}', photo=FSInputFile(path=os.path.join(theme, variant)))

    sql.execute("INSERT INTO logs (user_id, variant_number, theme_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", (user_id, variant_number, theme_id))
    db.commit()`


dp.run_polling(bot)
```

[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKdVu.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vo37C.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qA648.jpg)

We tried to install vpn, change the bot token, nothing worked, the result is the same

Comment: Well the error indicates an SSL error. So it's probably a network issue, possibly due a government blockage. Try a proxy.